# How do constraints work programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

I'm trying to learn how constraints work programmatically for iOS apps, by making a simple project (single view application) shown below:

[image]

I succeeded in creating the top space only using this code in viewDidLoad:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:_container
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self.view
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                   multiplier:1.0
                                   constant:200];

[self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];

myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
               constraintWithItem:_container
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
               toItem:nil
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
               multiplier:1.0
               constant:216];

[_container addConstraint:myConstraint];
```

but I failed to set the height of `_container` (UIView - subview of superview). How would I create multiple constraints in a case like this? Thank you.

UPDATE : I will manipulate the size of top-space programmatically so the `_container` will move up and down, or even offscreen.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a height constraint in code using visual format language : `"V:[view(==216.0)]"` or by using `constraintWithItem:` where the second item is `nil`, the second attribute is `NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute` and the constant value is your height.

Comment: Are you creating the contained view in code as well, or interface builder? Can you update your question to show the code?